# Pandas resample with overlap

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, resampling

I would like to resample my time indexed DataFrame with some overlapping.

For example:

```
>>> df
                     data
date                     
2018-03-09 12:00:00     1
2018-03-09 12:00:01     1
2018-03-09 12:00:02     1
2018-03-09 12:00:03     1
2018-03-09 12:00:04     1
2018-03-09 12:00:05     1
2018-03-09 12:00:06     1
2018-03-09 12:00:07     1
2018-03-09 12:00:08     1
2018-03-09 12:00:09     1
2018-03-09 12:00:10     1
2018-03-09 12:00:11     2
2018-03-09 12:00:12     2
2018-03-09 12:00:13     2
2018-03-09 12:00:14     2
2018-03-09 12:00:15     2
2018-03-09 12:00:16     2
2018-03-09 12:00:17     2
2018-03-09 12:00:18     2
2018-03-09 12:00:19     2
2018-03-09 12:00:20     2
2018-03-09 12:00:21     3
2018-03-09 12:00:22     3
2018-03-09 12:00:23     3
2018-03-09 12:00:24     3
2018-03-09 12:00:25     3
2018-03-09 12:00:26     3
2018-03-09 12:00:27     3
2018-03-09 12:00:28     3
2018-03-09 12:00:29     3
2018-03-09 12:00:30     3
```

The result should look like this after resampling with 10 seconds and 2 seconds overlap:

```
>>> df
                     data
date                     
2018-03-09 12:00:10     14
2018-03-09 12:00:20     28
2018-03-09 12:00:30     34
```

I tried it with grouping but it is very very slow on big datasets.

Is there a fast and efficient way to accomplish that?

Comment: `groupby` or `resample` require each row to belong to a unique group. You'll need other methods like `rolling` or `shift`ing. Are your data guaranteed to have a regular frequency of `1s`?

Comment: Also your output doesn't seem to make sense. What time periods are you grouping for each row in your output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your data are regularly spaced you can `concat` the shifted Series and then take a sum.

```
N = 10  # Every 10 seconds from first row
ov = 2  # 2s overlap on either side

pd.concat([df.shift(i).iloc[::N] for i in range(-ov, N+ov)], axis=1).sum(1)
```

---

```
date
2018-03-09 12:00:00     3.0
2018-03-09 12:00:10    15.0
2018-03-09 12:00:20    28.0
2018-03-09 12:00:30    34.0
dtype: float64
```

---

For multiple columns, turn this into a `groupby` along the columns axis:

```
df['data2'] = df['data']+1  # Another column

(pd.concat([df.shift(i).iloc[::N] for i in range(-ov, N+ov)], axis=1)
   .groupby(level=0, axis=1).sum())

                     data  data2
date                            
2018-03-09 12:00:00   3.0    6.0
2018-03-09 12:00:10  15.0   28.0
2018-03-09 12:00:20  28.0   42.0
2018-03-09 12:00:30  34.0   46.0
```

Comment: Ok, that's working with one column. What if I have multiple columns in the data frame?

Comment: @user1554681 replace the `.sum(1)` with `.groupby(level=0, axis=1).sum()` that way it will take the row-wise sum grouping like-named columns.